# reducuble polynomial in two variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-factorization

Let $f(x,y)=x^4-y^3 \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. I claim that $f$ is reducible but i don`t know how to find its irrdeucible factors. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The polynomial $x^4-y^3$ is in fact irreducible.

Comment: As pigeon says, this is in fact irreducible. Here is one way to see this: view as a polynomial in $(\mathbb{R}[x])[y]$. Then, this is a degree 3 polynomial and hence is reducible iff it has a root in $\mathbb{R}(x)$ (rational functions in $x$). Is there such a root?